# In std::iterator_traits, what is the difference between '::value_type *' and ::pointer?

Tags: c++, iterator, iterator-traits

I've read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) from Cppreference
I'm confusing about what is the difference between:

- `std::iterator_traits<it>::value_type *`
- and `std::iterator_traits<it>::pointer.`

I did dive in the text and try to figure out the difference, but the more I read the more I get confusing.
Something tells me they would be the same, but logically they seem not.
So what is the actual difference between them, I would like an example if possible.

Comment: Read the section **Specializations** on the referenced page and you see how they differ.

Comment: @273K in the specializations they look the same in those cases, but generally they seem not (according to the text right avove that section).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`value_type` is supposed to have cv-qualifiers (`const` and/or `volatile`) removed from it, so you could have e.g.:

```
using value_type = int;
using pointer = const int *;
using reference = const int &;
```

Also, for the quirky iterators that compute the result of dereferencing on the fly (such as `std::vector<bool>::iterator`), `reference` (the return type of `operator*`) and `pointer` (the [return type of `operator->`](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.traits#1)) can be proxy classes that merely pretend to be pointers/references.

The exact requirements on those proxy classes appear to be underspecified, but at least `reference` is expected to be convertible to `value_type`, and `pointer` is expected to overload `->` and work with [`std::to_address`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/to_address).

Comment: Ah! you point exactly to where i'm trying to look at. Thanks for your help.

Comment: it seems like the iterator "it" is "::pointer" itself?

Comment: @LiDaCute If the iterator happens to be a pointer, yes. If it's a class, then most likely no.

Comment: Ah! so in such case, we put in an interator in to find out itself. Like sometimes we forget our own name and then go and ask our mother :>

Comment: @LiDaCute You wouldn't intentionally call it on an interator that you already know is a pointer (then you can use its type directly). `::pointer`, like the rest of `iterator_traits`, is needed when writing templated algorithms for iterator types that you don't know in advance.

Answer (score 1):

They are usually the same in most cases that you will come across, except that a const iterator will have `const value_type*` for `pointer` and that sometimes `*pointer` is a proxy type rather than `value_type` itself (see other answers).

But also, the standard's definition for an iterator does not require that `pointer` is actually a raw native pointer. Instead it is also somewhat common to be a type that behaves *like* a raw native pointer. Such types are called "*fancy pointers*".

You can find a short explanation of fancy pointers [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator#Fancy_pointers) on cppreference.

One example is [`boost::interprocess::offset_ptr`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/interprocess/offset_ptr.html) which is a fancy pointer type that is used to address objects in memory shared between multiple processes. Because the shared memory is mapped to different base addresses in the different processes, you can't use a normal raw pointer. Instead you can only store the offset to a common reference point in memory (i.e. the offset pointer's location in the shared memory itself), so that all processes can agree where the offset pointer points. If you have e.g. a container implemented for shared memory using this offset pointer, then `std::iterator_traits<it>::pointer` would be that `offset_ptr<value_type>`, not `value_type*`, for iterators into that container.

Formally, the only purpose/requirement of `pointer` for an iterator is that it determines the result type of `operator->` or `void` if there is no `operator->`.

The only exception are *contiguous iterators* for which it must be possible to convert `pointer` to a native pointer and back through `to_address` and `to_pointer` since this mapping is used to define contiguity.

Comment: Are there any requirements of `pointer` other than just being what `operator->` returns? (And supposedly overloading `->`.) I have a hard time imagining how a generic algorithm would use this typedef. It's not like one would do `pointer p = iter.operator->();`...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes true, I got confused with the allocator requirements.